# C/C++ NaN constant (literal)?

Tags: c++, c, nan

Is this possible to assign a `NaN` to a `double` or `float` in C/C++? Like in JavaScript you do: `a = NaN`. So later you can check if the variable is a number or no.

Comment: Here I show how various NaNs look like when generated by different means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118408/what-is-difference-between-quiet-nan-and-signaling-nan/55648118#55648118

Answer (score 223, accepted):

In C, `NAN` is declared in `<math.h>`.

In C++, `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` is declared in `<limits>`.

But for checking whether a value is NaN, you can't compare it with another NaN value. Instead use `isnan()` from `<math.h>` in C, or `std::isnan()` from `<cmath>` in C++.

Comment: Or you can compare the number to itself – `x == x` returns `false` iff `x` is NaN.

Comment: @Archie: I don't think that's guaranteed in either language.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Not by the language standard but as far as I know it _should_ work if the compiler claims to be IEEE compliant.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Indeed, it's an option if you need obfuscation but not portability. Personally, I prefer portability without obfuscation, so I won't suggest it myself.

Comment: minor note: NAN is a float, not a double. [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/NAN/)

Comment: @MikeSeymour `(x == x) == false` is guaranteed in Java, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Float.java#Float.isNaN%28float%29

Comment: Thanks for this, I just solved a problem with an external library that just refused to compile properly because it did not understand what NAN meant.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` doesn't seem to be a constant in MSVC++2013.

Comment: Does `std::isnan(a)` return true if `a` is `-nan`?

Comment: What about if you can't use `std::numeric_limits`? Is there some other way to get `NaN`, such as a constant defined by dividing zero by zero, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: > Or you can compare the number to itself –

i have seen bugs from the compiler optimising this out. Always do an explicit check. Hunting this down is such a nightmare that its not worth the zero gain from doing it vs. any robust method.

Comment: Simon, there isn't a `-NaN`.  It's just `NaN`.  If you evaluate `-NaN` you get `NaN`.

There are a bunch of wierd NaNs that no-one uses, and std::isnan() should return true for all of them.  Or at least the quiet NaNs, I don't know if it will signal if passed a signalling NaN.

Answer (score 33):

As others have pointed out you are looking for `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` although I have to say I prefer the [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN) documents. Especially because this statement is a little vague:

> Only meaningful if std::numeric_limits::has_quiet_NaN == true.

and it was simple to figure out what this means on this site, if you check their section on [`std::numeric_limits::has_quiet_NaN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_quiet_NaN) it says:

> This constant is meaningful for all floating-point types and is guaranteed to be true if std::numeric_limits::is_iec559 == true.

which as explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) if `true` means your platform supports `IEEE 754` standard. This [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234468/do-any-real-world-cpus-not-use-ieee-754) explains this should be true for most situations.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done using the numeric_limits in C++:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/

These are the methods you probably want to look at:

```
infinity()  T   Representation of positive infinity, if available.
quiet_NaN() T   Representation of quiet (non-signaling) "Not-a-Number", if available.
signaling_NaN() T   Representation of signaling "Not-a-Number", if available.
```

Comment: +1. Wikipedia has some information on [quiet NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Quiet_NaN) and [signaling NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Signaling_NaN).

Answer (score 7):

> Is this possible to assign a NaN to a double or float in C ...?

Yes, since C99, (C++11) `<math.h>` offers the below functions:

```
#include <math.h>
double nan(const char *tagp);
float nanf(const char *tagp);
long double nanl(const char *tagp);
```

which are like their `strtod("NAN(n-char-sequence)",0)` counterparts and `NAN` for assignments.

```
// Sample C code
uint64_t u64;
double x;
x = nan("0x12345");
memcpy(&u64, &x, sizeof u64); printf("(%" PRIx64 ")\n", u64);
x = -strtod("NAN(6789A)",0);
memcpy(&u64, &x, sizeof u64); printf("(%" PRIx64 ")\n", u64);
x = NAN;
memcpy(&u64, &x, sizeof u64); printf("(%" PRIx64 ")\n", u64);
```

Sample output: (Implementation dependent)

```
(7ff8000000012345)
(fff000000006789a)
(7ff8000000000000)
```

---

> ...  check if the variable is a number or no.

Use `isnan(), std::isnan()` from `<math.h>, <cmath>`.

Comment: What are the differences between outputs for different strings? Which one should we use in typical numerical code?

Comment: @quant_dev `x = NAN;` fills most needs, else `x = nan("0x12345");` is a clear way to specify a payload.  Payload content differences is implementation defined.  Commonly the MSBit of the 52-bit payload is a _quiet_ / _signaling_ flag..  See [NAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point).

Comment: Great examples, thank you very much. When should we use for example `x = nan("0x12345");` instead of a general `NAN`? I mean why do we need to say `0x12345` is a nan?

Comment: @afp_2008 When not-a-number is implemented, there are usually many non-a-numbers.  Often quiet and signaling NANs are implemented.  When code wants to return something other than the default `NAN`, perhaps to signify quiet/signaling or some other meta data, `nan("some_numeric_string")`.  This is a bit of a re-hash of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691207/c-c-nan-constant-literal/61902369?noredirect=1#comment113258646_61902369). If you need more, perhaps post a _specific_ question? IIRC, one system tagged with the low bits of address to help facilitate _where_ the NAN originated.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica fyi, the provided link does not work.

Comment: @afp_2008 Curious, worked for me to get to my prior comment to quant_dev.

Answer (score -18):

yes, by the concept of pointer you can do it like this for an int variable:

```
int *a;
int b=0;
a=NULL; // or a=&b; for giving the value of b to a
if(a==NULL) 
  printf("NULL");
else
  printf(*a);
```

it is very simple and straitforward. it worked for me in Arduino IDE.

Comment: ```NULL``` and ```NaN``` are actually not the same

Comment: yes, they are basically different, but using NULL or NaN is same in the sense of checking if the variable is a number or no.

Comment: "_it worked for me_" but is not related to the question at all. The question is how to assign `NAN` to a `float` or `double`. This answer does not contain `NAN` or any `float` or `double`.

Comment: >using NULL or NaN is same in the sense of checking if the variable is a number or no.

Not quite - many comparisons with NaN operate differently from this.