# In C++, is exactly one of <, == and > guaranteed to be true on floats?

Tags: c++, floating-point, standards, floating-point-comparison

In C++, do I have a guarantee that, for any given `float a` and `float b`, one and only one of `a < b`, `a == b` and `a > b` is true?

If this differs between compilers and platforms, I am interested in Visual C++ on x86.

Comment: Not if your float is a NaN.

Comment: You probably want to modify this to 'non-NaN float values' to exclude the corner-case?

Comment: No, **at most one** of those is guaranteed to be true.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

No.

It's enough for either `a` or `b` to be `NaN` for each of `a < b`, `a == b` and `a > b` to be false.

If both `a` and `b` are non-NaN then exactly one of `a < b`, `a == b` or `a > b` has to be true.

In complement, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691341/139746) tells you how you can get **a** NaN value in C++ (there are several NaN values, that can be distinguished by inspecting their representations; they are all different from each other because NaN is never equal to anything,) and how you can test whether a value is a NaN (an idiomatic test to see if a variable `x` is a NaN is `x != x`, and indeed `std::isnan()` is often implemented this way, but some programmers who will have to read your code may be confused by it).

And then, if `a` and `b` are the results of previous computations, there is the problem of excess precision. See this [article](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00128124/document) for a discussion in C. The C99 standard solved the problem by making rules explicit for where excess precision could and could not occur, but despite C++ more or less inheriting these rules by deferring to the C standard for the definition of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` in `cfloat`, in practice C compilers take the rules more seriously than C++ compilers. For instance GCC implements the rules for C when compiling with `-std=c99`, and in this context you can rely on the property to hold, but as of this writing GCC does not implement these rules when used as a C++ compiler.

Comment: Will something like `0.0 / 0.0` not get __a__ NaN as well?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, that's a way to write it without relying on any header.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Depending on your FPU settings that might produce an FPU exception instead of a NaN.

Comment: Is the difference of behavior of GCC WRT C and C++ documented anywhere? Is it something related to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#PR323)?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, the last part of this answer describes exactly the same problem as the first part as the FAQ entry you linked to. Joseph Myers said when he implemented `-fexcess-precision=standard` for C that C++ didn't support it yet: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2008-11/msg00105.html . The second part of the FAQ affects how floating-point **expressions** are computed, so it does not handicap the comparison of **lvalues**. In any case, with GCC, `-ffp-contract=off` prevents the issue from the second part of the FAQ.

Comment: It's worth pointing the C++ faq about comparisons, which tells the same story: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html