# Default value for Template Class, C++

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to give a default value for a template class?

E.g. Say I have a class `TimeSeries`, that is templated.  And I have a function called `Foo()` that returns `T`.

```
template <typename T>
class TimeSeries
{
    T foo();
}
```

I want `Foo()` to do some calculation and return something of type `T`. But in case it can't, I want it to give a default value. If `T` was `double`, I want that to be `NaN`. If `T` was `int`, I want that to be `0`.

```
TimeSeries<double> t;
t.foo(); // returns NAN

TimeSeries<int> t;
t.foo(); // returns 0
```

How would I achieve that?

A bad solution is for `Foo()` to take in a default value.

```
template <typename T>
class TimeSeries
{
    T foo(T defaultValue)
    {
       T ret;
       // if OK
       ret = computeValue();
       // if not OK
       ret = defaultValue;
       return ret;
    }
}
```

So default value would be `0`, or `NaN`, depending on the user.

Or am I asking for a flawed design in the first place?

EDIT - 
A logical question would be to ask what happens if `T` is not `int` or `double`. What does a default value even mean?

The way I'm using `TimeSeries`, `T` is not exactly a general purpose type. It could only be 1 of `int`, `double`, and `string`. 
I thought about simply writing 3 separate `TimeSeries` classes, but that seems like a flawed approach.

I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: It can be done in many ways. The simplest one is `if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) return 0; else return NAN;`.

Comment: What would be the default value if `T` is something other than `double` or `int`?

Comment: I envision `TimeSeries` to not exactly be a general purpose class. The way I'm using it, it will only ever be `TimeSeries<double>`, `TimeSeries<int>`, and maybe `TimeSeries<std::string>`. Of course I could have written 3 separate `TimeSeries` classes, but I felt like that'd be an even weirder solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could declare the following template, `default_value<>`:

```
template<typename>
struct default_value;
```

Then, provide full specializations for `int` and `double` with a member called `value` which provides the desired default value:

```
template<>
struct default_value<int> {
   static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template<>
struct default_value<double> {
   static constexpr double value = NaN;
};
```

Then, in your `foo` function template, you can simply return that value:

```
return default_value<T>::value;
```

which will depend on `T`.

Comment: [`NaN` => `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16691207/3893262).

Answer (score 4):

since C++14 you can use a [variable template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template):

```
template <class T> constexpr T default_value = {};
template <>
constexpr double default_value<double> = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
```

```
template <typename T> class TimeSeries
{
    auto foo() -> T
    {
       T ret;

       if (condition)
         return ret;
       else
         return default_value<T>;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Or am I asking for a flawed design in the first place?

As far as I'm concerned it's a valid requirement.

I see two ways you can address that requirment.

1. You can use the `default_value` approach as suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48627388/434551).
2. If you have the option of using C++17, you can use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

   If you don't have the option of using C++17, you can emulate `std::optional` in a less sophisticated way by changing the return value to `std::pair<boo, T>` with the understanding that the `first` of the returned value is set to `false` if the computation was not successful and to `true` if the computation was successful.

Personally,  I would prefer the second solution. It does not rely on sentry values. It captures the state of whether the computation was successful in a clear and explicit manner.