# Why is 0 divided by 0 throwing an overflow error in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Why is `0/0` throwing `Overflow error` in VBA, while in .Net languages it is simply a `Division by 0` error?

---

E.g., in `C#` it is a `System.DivideByZeroException`

```
static void Main()
{
    int k = 0;
    int p = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(k/p);
}
```

---

`Div/0` error exists in `VBA`. **But** `0/0` gives an **overflow exception**, while anything else divided by 0 gives a `Div/0` exception:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    'Integer
    PrintAndCheck (11)      '- Division by zero error

    'Double
    PrintAndCheck (0.9)     '- Division by zero error

    'Long
    PrintAndCheck (50000)   '- Division by zero error

    'String
    PrintAndCheck ("1.1")   '- Division by zero error

    '----------------------------------------------------
    '----------------BUT---------------------------------
    '----------------------------------------------------

    'Integer
    PrintAndCheck (0)       '- Overflow?

End Sub

Public Sub PrintAndCheck(lngDivisor As Variant)

    On Error Resume Next

    Debug.Print lngDivisor / 0
    Debug.Print Err.Description & " from type -> " & VarType(lngDivisor)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

That's what you get in the immediate window:

```
Division by zero from type -> 2
Division by zero from type -> 5
Division by zero from type -> 3
Division by zero from type -> 8
Overflow from type -> 2
```

### Edit: To make the whole story more interesting:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print Evaluate("0/0")     'Division by 0 error (CVErr(xlErrDiv0)=2007)
    Debug.Print 0 \ 0               'Division by 0 error
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you *explicitly* tried 0 / 0?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog - in C# it does not compile, in VBA it gives `Overflow`

Comment: If every language behaved identically in all circumstances, there wouldn't be different languages. Since `0/0` is very poorly defined, there no single correct response to it.

Comment: It's an interesting question, which I think would be better if you left C# / .Net exceptions out of it, and re-worded it to compare VBA behavior when dividing by zero with a non-zero numerator VS. a zero numerator.

Comment: classic VB had A LOT of quirks and inconsistent behavior, which is one of the reasons many base behaviors were changed when they implemented the .NET platform.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that 0 / 0 is a special case.  The normal argument against calculations of the form x / 0 where x <> 0 is that there is no number y such that y * 0 = x, and that x / 0 is therefore undefined.  This is not the case for 0, as 0 * 0 is indeed 0.  So if VBA generates a different error for 0 / 0 as opposed to 1 / 0, I take my hat off to it!

Comment: Calculators sometimes give different errors for 0/0 and 1/0. My HP-39 calculator gives "Infinite Result" for 1/0 but "Undefined Result" for 0/0. Calling the 0/0 error an "overflow" error is perhaps a bit odd, but serviceable.

Comment: If you try same code in VB6 where you have control over optimization flags, checking "Remove floating point error checks" turns the errors into `-1,#IND` for `0/0`, `1,#INF` for `1/0`, and `-1,#INF` for `-1/0` (note the difference between `INF` and `IND`). It would then appear https://stackoverflow.com/a/347940/11683 explains why it is so (non-zero divided by zero is an infinity, zero divided by zero is a NaN). Apparently VB decides to expose the `NaN` as an overflow, which apparently is expected, as "[0/0 is not a divide by zero error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7212363/11683)".

Comment: @JonathanWillcock - see the edit, probably you would keep your hat on.

Comment: I still like Overflow as the Exception for 0/0. a/b = c is equivalent to a = bc As I wrote in my comment, a/b is undefined for a <> 0 and b=0 since there is no solution for c in a = bc. Note it is not infinity but undefined. As the dividor tends to 0 then the answer tends to infinity, is however true. The problem with 0/0 is not that in this case there is no solution for c, when re-written, but that every number is a solution. Again the set of all numbers is not the same as infinity but given that it includes massive numbers I think overflow is a good exception.

Comment: The last edit is actually not surprising. `Evaluate` does not raise an error, it returns a Variant value with an error flag, and there is no "overflow" flag available. The ``\`` is the integer division operator, so there is no floating point number that could contain an `#IND` to begin with.

Comment: Anyone willing to add an answer, explaining all the cases? :)

Comment: @GSerg - this thing with the flags is interesting. Can you make an answer with screenshots, I am not sure I have seen anythinglike this in `VBA`. Still, if it is `VB6`, it can be interesting again :)

Comment: @JonathanWillcock - I understood the reason for being an Overthrow Exception fan of `0/0`, but the point is that VBA is somehow not consistent there - e.g. `Debug.Print Evaluate("0/0")` gives `xlErrDiv0`

Comment: @Vityata It's just an educated guess. I don't know for a fact it's true. I can't turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will try to summarize the answers from the comments:

1. In VBA **0/0** throws an Overflow exception, because **0/0** is a specific case of division by **0**. Thus, it is a good idea to throw a different exception than the standard `Division by zero error`.
2. In VBA `Evaluate("0/0")` returns a `Division by zero error`, because Evaluate does not raise an error, it returns a Variant value with an error flag, and there is no "overflow" flag available.
3. In VBA integer division **0\0** returns a `Division by zero error`, because the result should be an integer value and #IND is a floating point value. As far as #IND cannot be returned, it gives the next best thing - `Division by zero error`.

More reading concerning **0/0** in other languages:

- [How to produce a NaN float in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212356/how-to-produce-a-nan-float-in-c/7212363#7212363)
- [VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/floating-point-division-operator)

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/floating-point-division-operator

Besides the obvious differences in implementation of languages and the way `VBA` handles `division`, MS Doc link above expands on the reasons for `overflow exception` , that if the operand data types are integer then it will throw `Overflow exception` (Last statement below)

[image]

Alternatively there is `\`  [division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator) that checks the range for you and throws `Division by zero` exception

Comment: That's an interesting reading indeed, but it is for `VB.Net`. In `VBA`, a `Single`, `Double` or even a `String` value of **0/0** would throw an Overthrow error.

Comment: Wouldn't division using string become overloaded and converted to number?

Comment: @While it is true that this is for `vb.net`, the rationale for raising an overflow error as opposed to a division by zero error is doubtless the same. Still, it would be good to find a link to the *VBA* or at least *VB6* documentation for this point.

Comment: @RYenugu - yes. The result would be a number. Or an error :)

Comment: I guess in my opinion the error type is dependent on the operand types in question, that's all I'm trying to say :)

Comment: @RYenugu - I understand, but in `VBA` zero is an `Integer`. See the updated version of the question.