# runtime error '6' overflow-vba

Tags: vba, excel

i have runtime error '6' overflow when i execute following code.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_CLICK()

If val(Label27) >= 0 And val(Label27) <= val(Label9) Then    
    Label35 = (val(Label13) - val(Label14) + 1) * val(Label27)/val(Label9)    
ElseIf val(Label27) >= val(Label9) And val(Label27) <= val(Label6) Then    
    Label35 = val(Label13) + 1    
Else     
    Label35 = (val(Label13) + 1) * val(Label6) / val(Label27)            
End If

end sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to divide by zero. Check the values of Label9 and Label27 are not zero.

Comment: No, division by zero raises runtime error 11

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?  What are the values of your `Label27`, etc, variables when it crashes?

Comment: when i run combobox in userform,the label 27 have not value yet,i think it be equal zero as default.

Comment: When it crashes, hover your mouse over each `Label27` type variable in the code - it should show what the actual value is.  That's what we need to know, not just what you **think** it will be.  (If our programs always used the values we **thought** they should be using, they would never crash on us!  :D )

Comment: Ahh - `0 / 0` gives an overflow, so @Olly was probably spot on.  So if `Label9` and `Label27` are both zero, or blank, your first `Label35 =` line will be executed and will overflow.

Comment: @YowE3K; You nailed it. Another quirk of VBA... You should post this as answer so that we can upvote and make this the solution.

Comment: label27 and label 9 is zero.thanks @Olly

Comment: thanks for guidance @yowe3k

Comment: @FunThomas - welcome to the club - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485285/why-is-0-divided-by-0-throwing-an-overflow-error-in-vba

Comment: @FunThomas Please check out Olly's answer and upvote if you feel it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to divide zero by zero. Check the values of `Label9` and `Label27` are not zero.

Normally a division by zero will generate a

> Run-time error '11': Division by zero

error, but if `Label9` is zero (or blank) **and** `(val(Label13) - val(Label14) + 1) * val(Label27)` evaluates to zero (probably because `Label27` is zero) you will be calculating `0 / 0` which causes VBA to generate a

> Run-time error '6': Overflow

error.

Answer (score 0):

An overflow may happen if VBA is using `int` as datatype and an intermediate result exceeds the size of an `int` - even if the final result is small enough to fit into an `int`

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1000 * 1000 / 2000    ' Will raise overflow
```

You should force VBA to use datatype `long`.
So instead of using function `val`, use function `CLng`.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = CLng(1000) * 1000 / 2000    ' Okay
i = CLng("1000") * CLng("1000") / cLng("2000")    ' Okay
```

As YowEwK statet, this maybe doesn't solve your issue. If not, define a variable for every value you are dealing with (as `long` or `double`), assign the value f the label to it and check the values of them in the debugger if the runtime error still happens:

```
Dim val27 As doubble
Dim val19 As doubble
val27 = Val(Label27)
val9 = Val(Label9)
...
```

BTW: You should consider to name all your fields and variables with something meaningful. And do not forget to add `Option explicit`

Comment: Sounds good, but the OP's code is using `Val` which means all the calcs should be being done as `Double`.  (At least a `TypeName(Val("1"))`, and even `TypeName(Val(CInt(1)))`, returns `Double`, so I can't see anything that would be dropping it back to an `Integer`.)