# DateSerial when arg is 0

Tags: vba, excel

I have noticed something strange. Let's say I have a function:

```
Function ds(l As Long) As String
  ds = DateSerial(Year(l), Month(l), Day(l))
End Function
```

When I type ds(date) I will get string representing current date. If I type ds(1) it returns 31/12/1899. ds(-1) returns 29/12/1899. And then, ds(0) brings: 00:00:00. One could expect 30/12/1899, coudn't he?
Well, it is not a matter of life and death, but I am curious, why DateSerial behave this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`0` is really a tough value to convert to date.
Thus, it is skipped. Otherwise it would have broken lots of business logic in programs. This is my personal finding with 0 in VBA - [Why is 0 divided by 0 throwing an overflow error in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485285/why-is-0-divided-by-0-throwing-an-overflow-error-in-vba)

---

**Longer answer:**

In general, `1` is the first date value in VBA and Excel.

In VBA, `1` is represented as `31.12.1899` 
In Excel it is represented as `01.01.1900` or `01.01.1904`, depending on whether you have enabled the 1904 Date system in Excel. [MSDN 1904 date system.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel)

The good thing is that `-1` (and all negative values) cannot be represented as dates in Excel, as it gives an error, thus there is one less problem:

[image]

---

**Easiest answer:**

DateSerial accepts arguments between 100 and 9999 for the year, thus `-1` is outside their range - [DateSerial MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateserial-function). `Year()` accepts from `1` to `9999` correspondingly, thus `-1` and `0` are also outside the boundaries. [Year MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/88k2aec8(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, anyway, argument -1 don't cause error in my little function. Only 0 returns unexpected result.

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec - that is because `DateSerial(1899,12,30)` is evaluated to `0` and there is no way to present it as a date. Thus, it gives `00:00:00`. See this by writing `?clng(DateSerial(1899,12,30))` in the immediate window.