# How to solve this overflow problems

Tags: vba, excel

May I ask why do line 5 causes overflow? i checked the data's ans will be 0 over 0, I guess this might be the problem but i am not sure, is there any solution to make this work?

```
HKColumn = 2

Do Until Cells(6, HKColumn).Value = 0

    Cells(34, 27).Value = (Cells(6, HKColumn) - Cells(5, HKColumn)) / (Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(6, HKColumn) - Worksheets("Total").Cells(5, HKColumn))
    Cells(34, 26).Value = "2018 " + Cells(3, HKColumn)
    Cells(34, 17).Value = (Cells(11, HKColumn) - Cells(10, HKColumn)) / (Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(11, HKColumn) - Worksheets("Total").Cells(10, HKColumn))
    Cells(34, 16).Value = "2018 " + Cells(3, HKColumn)

    Cells(32, 27).Value = (Cells(5, HKColumn) - Cells(4, HKColumn)) / (Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(5, HKColumn) - Worksheets("Total").Cells(4, HKColumn))
    Cells(32, 26).Value = "2017 " + Cells(3, HKColumn)
    Cells(32, 17).Value = (Cells(10, HKColumn) - Cells(9, HKColumn)) / (Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(10, HKColumn) - Worksheets("Total").Cells(9, HKColumn))
    Cells(32, 16).Value = "2017 " + Cells(3, HKColumn)

    HKColumn = HKColumn + 1

Loop
```

Comment: how is HKColumn declared? Have you put is as a long just to be careful

Comment: Which line is line 6?

Comment: @Vityata i was just about to ask that!

Comment: I did declared as Long

Line 6:  Cells(34, 17).Value = (Cells(11, HKColumn) - Cells(10, HKColumn)) / (Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(11, HKColumn) - Worksheets("Total").Cells(10, HKColumn))
    Cells(34, 16).Value = "2018 " + Cells(3, HKColumn)

Comment: So you have `0/0`?  In VBA this gives `6` (Overflow) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485285/why-is-0-divided-by-0-throwing-an-overflow-error-in-vba

Comment: FYI all of the values are 0 in the cells in this case, but the values will change monthly, does it mean that theres no way i can solve it  if all values are 0?

Comment: to append strings use `&` instead of `+`  Because `Debug.Print "2017 " + 5` it will start calculating even if 2017 is a string!

Comment: You can always make a check whether the divisor is a not a `0` and continue with the calculation then. Or the easiest & dirtiest solution - Write `On Error Resume Next` before `HKColumn = 2` and it would "work".

Answer (score 0):

If all the values are 0, it would give Overflow, because 0/0 throws overflow error in Excel - [Why is 0 divided by 0 throwing an overflow error in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485285/why-is-0-divided-by-0-throwing-an-overflow-error-in-vba)

Two ways to solve the problem:

- Really not recommended way, which would force the VBA to ignore every error - Write `On Error Resume Next` on the top of your code. Then write `On Error GoTo 0` at the bottom.
- Always make a check whether the divisor is different than 0. This is a standard in programming, as far as dividing by 0 is not allowed. Thus something like this or even make it a separate function:

---

```
If (Cells(6, HKColumn) - Worksheets("Total").Cells(5, HKColumn))) <> 0 Then
        Cells(34, 27).Value = (Cells(6, HKColumn) - Cells(5, HKColumn)) / the-non-zero-val
End If
```