# How to handle possibility of invalid data with NaNs

Tags: c, floating-point, nan

I was reading a [book](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiX6a_s7IbkAhWwxoUKHWEBDx0QFjAAegQIABAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsistemas.fciencias.unam.mx%2F~gcontreras%2Fjoomla15%2Ftmp%2FNumerical_Computing_with_IEEE_Floating_Point_Arithmetic.pdf&usg=AOvVaw378VFZSh1Pyf11ukIYy3eR) 
about IEEE standard. and I countered to this part in p43(58):

> More generally,  NaNs provide a very  convenient  way for a 
>   programmer  to  handle the  possibility  of invalid data  or  other 
>   errors  in  many contexts.  Suppose we wish  to write a  program  to 
>   compute  a  function  that  is not  defined  for some input  values. 
>   By setting  the  output  of the  function  to  NaN  if the  input  is
>   invalid or  some  other  error takes  place  during  the  computation 
>   of the  function,  the  need  to  return  special  error messages  or 
>   codes  is  avoided.

I tried to `return NAN` but that doesn't seem to be right. more generally I want to know how to use `NAN` in practice in code. there isn't much information about this topic out there.

**UPDATE**:

for clarifying things I have to ask this:

How to define some function like `sqrt` which for some input like `sqrt(-1)` is undefined using `NAN`? I don't see how this can heppen because returning  `NAN` prints `nan` as output.

as the book say in the same page:

> The  square  root  operation  provides  a  good  example  of the  use 
>   of NaNs.  Before  the IEEE  standard, an attempt  to take the  square 
>   root  of a negative number might  resultonly  in  the  printing  of an
>   error  message  and  a  positive  result  being  returned.   The user 
>   might  not  notice  that  anything  had  gone  wrong.  Under  the 
>   rules  of the  IEEEstandard,  the  square  root  operation  is 
>   invalid  if  its  argument  is  negative,  and  the standard  response 
>   is to  return  a NaN

Comment: You shouldn't create nans yourself synthetically. They should arise from the use of C operators and functions on your values.

Comment: Otherwise [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33154242/918959)

Comment: Why does `return NAN;` not seem to be right?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Creating a NaN is correct behavior when a function determines input is outside its domain.

Answer (score 1):

NaNs are generated by any kind of invalid floating point calculation, such as doing 0/0 or Inf-Inf. This can be an unexpected result of performing calculations using certain values.

There are multiple ways in which this is may be used in programs. For simple, text or console based applications, the result of your calculation may be normally printed as-is using `printf` and the `"%f"` format-string. If something went wrong and the calculation resulted in a NaN, `printf` detects this and prints NaN instead of any actual number.

In other cases, you might want to detect yourself whether the result is NaN. But then there are multiple NaN representations so it is not enough to check `if(num == NAN)`. However, you could use the following idiom:

```
if(num == num)
    printf("Calculation valid!"); 
else
    printf("Calculation invalid!");
```

On any C compiler compliant to IEEE754 floating point standard, the expression `(num == num)` evaluates to false iff `num` is a float/double containing one of the NaN representations.
Another option is to use the `isnan(num)` standard library function from math.h.

If you want to *generate* a NAN, you could use `nan("")` from math.h or `strtod("NAN")`. Keep in mind that this is only one of various NaN representations!

EDIT: Fixed incorrect attribution to C standard for `(num != num)`; Thanks @chux!

Comment: C also allows `num == num` to be true when `num` is a NaN - it is implementation defined.  The "guarantee" one needs is not in C, but IEEE math, something not guaranteed by C.

Comment: @chux Oh yes, thanks for pointing out! The guarantee can be perhaps rephrased as being given by IEEE754 compliant C compilers?

Comment: Perhaps.  Compliance to IEEE754 is rarely 100%.  Still many C compilers/platforms are very IEEE754-like. NAN is one area that is often marginally supported correctly.  `isnan(num)` is the best solution.